# Is there an equivalent for Guice install(new ModuleA) in Dagger?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, dagger

I'm trying to migrate a project from Guice to Dagger, and I can't figure out what to do with modules including other modules using `install`. How would I switch even a really basic example like this to Dagger?

```
public class ModuleA extends AbstractModule {

  public ModuleA() {
    ...
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    install(new ModuleB());
  }
}
```

Where ModuleB would provide its own dependencies.

What would the dagger equivalent of this look like? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make one module include another in Dagger, use `includes` in your `@Module` annotation:

```java
@Module(includes = {ModuleB.class})
public class ModuleA {
    // ...
}
```